# How to play multiple sound files simultaneously?

Tags: android, media-player, soundpool

For my application I need to play multiple tracks simultaneously and some kinf of listener to know when a track is finished.

SoundPool seems to be the obvious choice, but unfortunately I could't find a solution to get notified when a track ends.

I also thought about using multiple instances of Android's MediaPlayer, but I'm afraid of getting performance issues.

Are there any other options?

Comment: Sometimes is better to test our theories before being afraid of them. You should try and see if that creates a performance issueIf I'm not wrong, there is a listener (onCompletition) which executes when the MediaPlayer has finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use MediaPlayer, you can use OnCompletionListener. It also has no problem of playing multiple tracks at the same time. Like gian1200 says. Try it, perhaps the performance is not really an issue.